# Misconception about electrons pushing each other

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields

There is a misconception that electrons push each other from their mutual repulsion within a circuit. Rather they are pushed by the electric field. I also understand that the electric has the energy rather than the electrons being charged carriers. However, I can't seem to understand why we need wires at all when energy is in the fields rather than the electrons. What is flawed with my logic?

Comment: The electric field is created by charge carriers inside the battery generating a potential difference, the wire connects the two ends of the battery, setting up the $\mathbf{E} = \mathbf{\nabla} V$ that pushes the electrons.

Comment: It is mostly convenience? You can have a vacuum tube, ie electrons flying through a vacuum as part of the circuit; you can exploit photoelectric effect; you can do something else. Note that you do need the charges to flow to get the magnetic field part, and to extract the energy out of the fields.

Comment: @r_phys the battery already setup the E field beforehand (but the wires greatly concentrate them), and it is instead the B field, due to charges flowing, that is really needed for the energy flow via the fields to be directed efficiently as they are. Providing the efficient flow of charges is what the wires are kinda doing for us.

Comment: There are EM fields around the wire. But electrons in the wire are also quanta of a field, (as photons are quanta of EM fields). See for example https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/415176/195949.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent yep you're right, sorry. the $\mathbf{E}$ field is set up in free space as soon as there is charge separation, but the motion of the electrons can't happen because there are no delocalized electrons in the air. When you provide a wire, the delocalized electrons can move and set up a magnetic field.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is better to talk about a scalar potential rather than a vector field, when one needs an "energy". They are related, for a vector like polarization, it is certainly better to use a "field" than a potential.

As stated, in a conducting wires, the repulsion is not important compared to the kinetic energy, it is due to unfilled delocalized states, when a "field" is applied the direction of the particles are long the field and the motion is collective, there is no significant interaction affecting this process except when they are strongly scattered in an inhomogeneous wire.

There is an ionization energy or a potential cost to having free electrons before they move along a field forfree atoms or insulators. In a conducting wire, this ionization is not needed for an electron to be transferred because the states overlap and the conduction is efficent without a significant cost.